# Client Side XSLT, Internet Explorer does not cache XSLT

Tags: xml, performance, internet-explorer, xslt, caching

I am using client side XSLT to render an XML document as HTML. The XSLT is referenced in the XML file and executed automatically by the browser, such as this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="xslt.php"?>
<root>1421744643</root>
```

This works as expected, however on Internet Explorer (9, 10 and 11) I notice that the XSLT file will be downloaded for every request, although the HTTP response that serves the file is marked as cacheable.

The HTTP response for the XSLT is actually

```
Date: Tue, 20 Jan 2015 09:03:42 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.29 (Unix)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.29
Cache-Control: max-age=100000
Content-Type: text/xsl
Connection: Keep-Alive
Age: 705
Content-Length: 583

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
      <html>
      <head>

      </head>
      <body>
      <div>
        <div>XSLT time: 1421744622</div>
        <div>XML time:
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </div>
        <div>
          <a href="xml.php">reload</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      </body>
      </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Other browsers such as Chrome or Firefox do cache the XSLT and will only fetch the XML document.

Is this a known problem with Internet Explorer? Are there any workarounds?
A testpage for this is
http://www.carsten-leue.de/test/iframe_xslt/index.html

Comment: This might be relevant: http://support.microsoft.com/KB/811045, and this: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/d8959d3e-caff-4b95-bc22-b95018cac2f3/xslimport-target-caching-in-ie-msxml2domdocument0?forum=xmlandnetfx

Comment: Hi Mathias, thanks for your answer. The first link refers to IE6 however the issue occurs on IE9/10/11. The second link relates to using script to trigger the transform. In my usecase however I am pointing the browser directly to the XML file and let the browser execute the transform. There is no script in between that I could use to tweak the transform. 
Do you know if there is any way to debug (on an MSXML level) what exactly the browser does when executing this implicit transform?

Comment: As far as I know, you can't debug IE transforms. But perhaps it would be worth checking which version of MSXML is installed? This might help: http://www.netcrucible.com/xslt/msxml-faq.htm#Q5 , but it's quite old, or http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973686. Sorry for only pointing to vague links!

Comment: You might also have to prevent old versions of MSXML from being used in IE, https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms14-033 (under "Workarounds").

Comment: Hi Mathias,

the version actually being used is MSXML6 (according to the system-property('ms:version')):

Version: 1
Vendor: Microsoft
Vendor URL: http://www.microsoft.com
MS Version: 6

Answer (score 1):

Use the `createProcessor` method:

> To cache a compiled XSLT style sheet, load an XSLT style sheet into an IXSLTemplate object. This object is free-threaded and stateless, so it can be stored in shared Active Server Pages (ASP) application state. Then to transform a given document using this template, create an IXSLProcessor object using the createProcessor method. The IXSLProcessor object stores the state for one transform call and has a rental-threading model.

```
var xslt = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.3.0");
var xslDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.3.0");
var xslProc;
xslDoc.async = false;
xslDoc.load("createProcessor.xsl");

if (xslDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) 
   {
   var myErr = xslDoc.parseError;
   location.hash = "You have the following error: " + myErr.reason;
   }

else 
   {
   xslt.stylesheet = xslDoc;
   var xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.3.0");
   xmlDoc.async = false;
   xmlDoc.load("books.xml");

   if (xmlDoc.parseError.errorCode != 0) 
      {
      var myErr = xmlDoc.parseError;
      location.hash = "You have the following error: " + myErr.reason;
      } 

    else 
      {
      xslProc = xslt.createProcessor();
      xslProc.input = xmlDoc;
      xslProc.addParameter("param1", "Hello");
      xslProc.transform();
      location.hash = xslProc.output;
      }
   }
```

or the embedded stylesheet technique:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="application/xslt+xml" href="#style1"?>
<!DOCTYPE doc SYSTEM "doc.dtd">
<doc>
<head>
<xsl:stylesheet id="style1"
                version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<xsl:import href="doc.xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="id('foo')">
  <div><xsl:apply-templates/></div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="xsl:stylesheet">
  <!-- ignore -->
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
<para id="foo">
...
</para>
</body>
</doc>
```

> Because multiple simultaneous clients may be calling objects more or less simultaneously (simultaneously on multi-processor systems), objects must synchronize their internal state by themselves. Interfaces are not marshaled between threads. Previous Microsoft information and documentation has sometimes referred to this model as the "free-threaded model."
>
> Some transforms are only partially successful. For example, the output has missing attributes.
>
> The problem occurs when you invoke `LoadXML` twice on a `FreeThreadedDOMDocument` before using the `FreeThreadedDOMDocument` as the source document in the transform.

**References**

- [MSXML with Internet Explorer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms760232)
- [Building MSXML Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753804)
- [MSXML Roadmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152146)
- [Once per session cache syncmode revalidates resources every time I start Internet Explorer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/06/15/once-per-session-cache-syncmode-revalidates-resources-every-time-i-start-internet-explorer.aspx)
- [Caching Improvements in Internet Explorer 9](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/07/14/caching-improvements-in-internet-explorer-9.aspx)
- [Browser Cache Vary Broken](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/browser-cache-vary-broken/)
- [XSLT 1.0 Biggest Issues (kind of ) Solved](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/xmlteam/archive/2011/10/09/xslt-1-0-biggest-issues-kind-of-solved.aspx)
- [List of Microsoft XML parser (MSXML) versions](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/269238)
- [IXSLTemplate: createProcessor Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753809)
- [MSXML: Intermittent failure to process xslt completely, transformNodeToObject followed by transformNode, in multithreaded environment](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/968705)
- [INFO: Descriptions and Workings of OLE Threading Models](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/150777)
- [Embedded Stylesheet Modules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#embedded)

Comment: Hi Paul, how does this address the issue? This Looks like a rewrite Expression for the HTTP server, but the HTTP headers have always been ok. It's the client side MSXML library that does not cache.

In the meantime I have also gotten feedback from the Microsoft Support Team confirming that this is indeed a restriction of MSXML.

Comment: I noticed that the `Accept` header is different when the XSLT template loads initially versus subsequent requests. In my case, it changed from `application/xml` to `text/html`, so I added this to forbid that and other [behavior](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/07/01/ie-and-the-accept-header.aspx).  `application/xml` is a [recognized MIME type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775147) which should be used rather than `text/xsl` to properly interpret the request headers.